# Shell BrowseForFolder preselected path

Tags: winapi, vb6, shell32.dll

I have this call:

```
oShell.BrowseForFolder(Me.hwnd, "Select path:", 0, "C:\dir\")
```

This opens a standard file browser dialog with "C:\dir\" as root.
My problem is that you can not browse above the root folder. (as specified in doc [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774065(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774065%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Any suggestions on oppening this dialog with a selected path and full browsing posibility?

Thanks

Comment: Well, the underlying implementation (SHBrowseForFolder) has the same limitation so you're not going to have any luck using this API.

Comment: @Luke On the contrary, it's perfectly possible through `SHBrowseForFolder`.

Comment: Nice.  Didn't even know about the callback mechanism.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to do this involves calling the underlying API, [`SHBrowseForFolder()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762115%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Since you want the entire shell namespace to be available you need to pass `NULL` as [`pidlRoot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773205%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). In order to select your desired folder you will need to provide a callback in [`lpfn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773205%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Make this callback respond to [`BFFM_INITIALIZED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762598%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) by setting the selected folder. This selection is performed by sending the `BFFM_SETSELECTION` message to the dialog's window handle (passed to the callback function).

No code because I don't have VB6, but hopefully this outline of the method is enough to get you on your way.

Comment: +1 Karl Peterson's excellent VB6 website has some VB6 code showing this technique. I have provided the link in my answer

Answer (score 5):

Karl E Peterson's excellent website contains a sample which demonstrates the API call `SHBrowseForFolder` with a callback, as in David Heffernan's answer.

[The KeyStuff project](http://vb.mvps.org/samples/KeyStuff/)

Look at `MFolderBrowse.bas`, routine `BrowseForFolderByPIDL` which passes a callback function `BrowseCallbackProc`.

Comment: +1 good work, I know nothing about vb so it's good to get input from someone who does

Answer (score 3):

Try the old [CCRP](http://ccrp.mvps.org/index.html?http://ccrp.mvps.org/download/ccrpdownloads.htm) project.  It has a nicely done implementation of the Browse dialog.  I used it in several of my projects and it has properties to address the issue you are having.

Answer (score 0):

Here a code ready for copy and paste in a C++ class:

```
// static
int CALLBACK Func::FolderBrowserCallback(HWND h_Dlg, UINT uMsg, LPARAM lParam, LPARAM lpData)
{
    if (uMsg == BFFM_INITIALIZED)
    {
        // Requires Windows XP or higher
        SendMessageW(h_Dlg, BFFM_SETEXPANDED, TRUE, lpData);
    }
    return 0;
}

// returns an empty string u16_PathOut if an error occurrs or if the user cancels the dialog
void Func::GetOpenFolder(HWND           h_Owner, 
                         const WCHAR* u16_Title,     // IN:  Title at the top of dialog
                         int          s32_CsidlRoot, // IN:  Root folder for treeview (CSIDL_DRIVES -> My Computer)
                         const WCHAR* u16_Preselect, // IN:  NULL or the folder to be preselected and expanded
                         WCHAR*       u16_PathOut)   // OUT: selected path
{
    u16_PathOut[0] = 0;

    // CoInitialize(NULL);
    // InitCommonControls();

    ITEMIDLIST* pk_RootPIDL = NULL; // NULL -> Root = Desktop
    SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(h_Owner, s32_CsidlRoot, &pk_RootPIDL);

    BROWSEINFOW k_Info = {0};
    k_Info.hwndOwner = h_Owner;
    k_Info.pidlRoot  = pk_RootPIDL;
    k_Info.lpszTitle = u16_Title;
    k_Info.ulFlags   = BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS | BIF_USENEWUI;

    if (u16_Preselect)
    {
        k_Info.lpfn   = FolderBrowserCallback;
        k_Info.lParam = (LPARAM)u16_Preselect;
    }

    // DO NOT DISABLE Wow64FsRedirection HERE !!
    LPITEMIDLIST pk_IDlist = SHBrowseForFolderW(&k_Info);
    if (pk_IDlist)
    {
        SHGetPathFromIDListW(pk_IDlist, u16_PathOut);
        CoTaskMemFree(pk_IDlist);
    }

    CoTaskMemFree(pk_RootPIDL);
}
```