# Open directory chooser dialog in specific dir

Tags: winapi, vba, lotusscript

I've got the following code to display a directory chooser dialog

```
Function selectOutputFolder(lastPath As String) As String
    Const BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE = &H00000040
    Dim objShell As Variant
    Dim objFolder As Variant
    Dim objFolderItem As Variant
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a directory", BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE, lastPath)
    If Not (objFolder Is Nothing) Then
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
        selectOutputFolder = objFolderItem.Path 
    End If
End Function
```

I was playing around with the 4th parameter of `BrowseForFolder` which is only a limit for the directory traversal and not to jump into this folder on open.

This is implemented into a lotus script agent, so if you know any alternative in vba or lotusscript, let me know!

Comment: which application you run it from?? the shell window you use is for folders only while you ask for 'file chooser'- which of two is your goal?

Comment: I fixed that, sorry. Ofc I mean "directory", not file.

Comment: which application you run it from??

Comment: As I said, it's inside of a LotusScript agent (Lotus Notes) which is similiar to VBA

Comment: have you seen [that Q+A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270775/shell-browseforfolder-preselected-path)

Comment: I'm not really into VBA and LotusScript etc. but I'll give it a try, thanks!

Comment: Why not use the LotusScript Standard? Look at this in the Lotus Help: stringArray = notesUIWorkspace .SaveFileDialog(  directoriesOnly  , [title$] , [filters$] , [initialDirectory$] , [initialFile$] )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a "Standard" way to do this in LotusScript by using the SaveFileDialog- Method of the NotesUIWorkspace- Class.

```
'...your sub goes around this
Dim ws as New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim varPaths as Variant
varPaths = ws.SaveFileDialog(  True  , "Choose file" , "" , lastPath )
If not isEmpty( varPaths ) then
  selectOutputFolder = varPaths(0)
End If
```

Comment: Not sure why I used such a complicated way. Works like a charm, thanks